# The length of word index in the Keras Tokenizer

Tags: python, keras

Consider the following code applied to the [IMDB dataset](http://mng.bz/0tIo). The printed length of `word_index` is always 88582 regardless of the value of `max_words`. I think it should be `min(max_words,88582)`. What is wrong?

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
max_words = 100
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
print(len(tokenizer.word_index))
```

Comment: I think you will find your answer here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7551

Comment: Thanks, @Minion. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

max_words is the vocabulary size. So the result shape is (88582,100)